# .NET Core Dependency Injection and services that utilize frequently rotated authorization keys

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

### Issue Summary

I have multiple ASP.NET Core applications that connect to Azure resources such as CosmosDB, Azure Storage Queues, Azure Event Hubs, etc. All of these resources can utilize [Shared Access Signature (SAS) tokens for authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/storage-dotnet-sas-getting-started/storage-dotnet-sas-getting-started/). These tokens expire which presents a problem when my application starts up and initializes the service *once upon startup* via `services.AddSingleton<T>()` (or a similar option).

For example, what I typically do is read the SAS token from a file upon startup (likely mounted to my pod as a volume in Kubernetes but I am not sure that's terribly relevant). That SAS token is then provided to an [Azure Storage Queue Client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Storage.Queues_12.8.0/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Queues/README.md) constructor, like this:

```cs
    string sharedAccessSignature = File.ReadAllText(pathToSasToken);

    services.AddSingleton<Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient>((sp) => 
    {
        return new Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient(queueUri,
            new AzureSasCredential(sharedAccessSignature),
            new Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClientOptions()
            {
                MessageEncoding = Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueMessageEncoding.Base64
            });
    });
```

Unfortunately, I think this means once my SAS token expires, my `QueueClient` will no longer be able to connect to my Azure Storage Queue without restarting my whole application. Somehow, I need to re-read an updated SAS token from my file while I remain running. (I have another process running in my cluster that provides SAS tokens to my pods).

### Possible Solutions

I figure the [IOptionsMonitor approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0) could be useful but unfortunately, the SDKs for these clients don't accept an `IOptionsMonitor<T>` in their constructors so they don't seem to be capable of re-reading new tokens at runtime -- at least not using `IOptionsMonitor`.

Another approach could be to use [Transient or Scoped service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes) but that requires I use the same service lifetimes in my whole dependency chain... So if I have a singleton like a [HostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) running, I cannot resolve a Transient or Scoped service from that without unpredictable results (AFAIK). (**Update 12/31/2021** - This is actually not true. [Microsoft provides guidance on how to consume a scoped service in a HostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) which is actually a good example that demonstrates how one can use Scoped services and manage the lifetimes on your own).

I could also just manually re-create my clients as my code is running but that seems to defeat the purpose of using the .NET service provider and DI pattern.

Am I missing an obvious solution to this that I'm just not seeing in Microsoft's documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing Managed Identities. Rather than trust on SAS tokens, you assign a Managed Identity to your ASP.NET app, and grant access to this identity to connect to the required services.

Benefits:

- no need to redeploy / acquire new SAS token when it changes / expires
- external users won't be able to impersonate this identity (if someone get access to the SAS token, they will be able to use it outside the scope of your app)

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-managed-identity

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/event-hubs-managed-identity

https://cmatskas.com/setting-up-managed-identities-for-asp-net-core-web-app-running-on-azure-app-service/